# How to prevent infinite recursion in a non-destructive way?

Tags: java, recursion

that's my first question here, so I'm apologizing in advance if I didn't data-mined well enough and duplicate the question.

So I'm trying to create some sort of a game where at some point you have a matrix like this:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|h|h|h|h|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|#|#|#|_|_|
|_|_|_|#|_|_|
|_|h|_|_|_|_|
|_|h|#|_|_|_|
```

And I need a method that checks if there are "elements" made up only by 'h'-es and if it finds one, to change all chars from 'h' to something else like 'd' for example so it becomes:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|d|d|d|d|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|#|#|#|_|_|
|_|_|_|#|_|_|
|_|h|_|_|_|_|
|_|h|#|_|_|_|
```

While it shouldn't change the other 'h'-es, that touch '#'-s
I can either use for-cycles to run through the whole matrix, or start directly from the element, as I have the arr[y][x] coordinates. Either way, I'm using recursion to check the neighbors, but how do I prevent the method from stepping in back to the previous element and oscillate between them until... StackOverflow occurs? So far this is where I am:

```
public class matrixRec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matrix = {
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ','h','h','h','h',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ','#','#',' '},
            {' ','h',' ',' ','#','#'},
            {' ','h','#',' ',' ',' '}
        };
        System.out.println(elementChange(matrix, 1, 2));
    }
    static boolean elementChange(char[][] matrix, int y, int x){

        if (matrix[y][x] == ' '){
            return true;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == '#'){
            return false;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == 'h'){
            return (elementChange(matrix, y, x-1) && elementChange(matrix, y, x+1));
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So is there a way I prevent infinite recursion, without changing the 'h'-es, until I am sure that they're all 'h'?

Comment: Read up on graph searching (try breadth-first). You need to keep track of visited cells, either with a list or a boolean matrix.

Comment: What's your terminating case? That you visit all n cells? Why not keep a counter that when evaluated true against your n celled matrix, terminate the recursion

Comment: You basically want a flood-fill algorithm :)

Comment: you will not get infinite loop, you will get `ArrayOutOfBoudsException`. add some checks that you don't get out of the array's size, and this should be your terminate case

Comment: Thanks guys, I though of making and accessory boolean array just after I went to bed last night :)
I'm gonna try it out now
About the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds - the upper code is just an example, I have coordinates-validation in the actual code

Comment: Tested it out - works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to do:

**Create a boolean aray to check visited cells each time we check an area**

```
public class matrixRec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matrix = {
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ','h','h','h','h',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ','#','#',' '},
            {' ','h',' ',' ','#','#'},
            {' ','h','#',' ',' ',' '}
        };
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[6][6] //boolean arrays default to false
        System.out.println(elementChange(matrix, 1, 2, visited));
    }
    static boolean elementChange(char[][] matrix, int y, int x. boolean[][] visited){
        if(visited[y][x]) return ((matrix[y][x] == ' ' || matrix[y][x] == 'h')? true: false);
        visited[y][x] = true; //We have visited this cell
        if (matrix[y][x] == ' '){
            return true;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == '#'){
            return false;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == 'h'){
            return elementChange(matrix, y, x-1,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y, x+1,visited);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Are we just checking up left and right? What about up and down?**

```
public class matrixRec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matrix = {
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ','h','h','h','h',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ','#','#',' '},
            {' ','h',' ',' ','#','#'},
            {' ','h','#',' ',' ',' '}
        };
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[6][6] //boolean arrays default to false
        System.out.println(elementChange(matrix, 1, 2, visited));
    }
    static boolean elementChange(char[][] matrix, int y, int x. boolean[][] visited){
        if(visited[y][x]) return ((matrix[y][x] == ' ' || matrix[y][x] == 'h')? true: false);
        visited[y][x] = true; //We have visited this cell
        if (matrix[y][x] == ' '){
            return true;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == '#'){
            return false;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == 'h'){
            return elementChange(matrix, y, x-1,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y, x+1,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y-1, x,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y+1, x,visited);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Use a conditional to only change areas that we want to**

```
public class matrixRec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] matrix = {
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ','h','h','h','h',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ',' ',' ','#','#',' '},
            {' ','h',' ',' ','#','#'},
            {' ','h','#',' ',' ',' '}
        };
        boolean visited[][] = new boolean[6][6] //boolean arrays default to false
        System.out.println(elementChange(matrix, 1, 2, visited));
    }
    static boolean elementChange(char[][] matrix, int y, int x. boolean[][] visited){
        if(visited[y][x]) return ((matrix[y][x] == ' ' || matrix[y][x] == 'h')? true: false);
        visited[y][x] = true; //We have visited this cell
        if (matrix[y][x] == ' '){
            return true;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == '#'){
            return false;
        }
        else if (matrix[y][x] == 'h'){

            if((elementChange(matrix, y, x-1,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y, x+1,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y-1, x,visited) && elementChange(matrix, y+1, x,visited))
                matrix[y][x] = 'd'; //Will only change areas that were searched to not be next to a #
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**For the future**

This is an area of algorithms that takes a little bit of thought and planning. For future research/programs be sure to do some searching on flood fills, recursive backtracking, graph searching, and recursive maze solving.